# How to mount an ext4 filesystem with specific permissions?

Tags: mount, file-permissions, ext4, torque

I want to mount `/home` such that any user can read and write to his/her own directory but only a certain user has execute permission.

We have a queue system (torque) and I want users not to be able to run executables outside it. Torque can be configured to execute scripts under a certain user.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the EXT4 filesystem level.  You may be able to do it using SELinux or Apparmour.

Something else to look into would be "jails" - Unix has a concept of limiting the root of the filesystem to a given subdirectory - if you are able to run torque in an appropriately configured jail that might do the trick - but I've not come across this software before today, so I don't know if that can be done or is appropriate.